# Remove keys of object based on other object

Tags: javascript

I need a way to automatically remove keys of a object to have same keys of other.

Example:

```
var objA = {key1:1, key2:2, key3:3};
var objB = {key1:4, key2:5, key3:6, key4:7, key5:8}
```

In this case I want my `objB`to keep only `key1`, `key2`, and `key3` because those are shared between these 2 objects.

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to achieve what you want.

```js
var objA = {key1:1, key2:2, key3:3};
var objB = {key1:4, key2:5, key3:6, key4:7, key5:8};
Object.keys(objB).forEach(function(key){
   if(!objA[key]){
     delete objB[key];
   }
});
console.log(objB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for..in` to loop over the object,`hasOwnProperty` to check if the object have a property and `delete` to delete a key

```js
var objA = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2,
  key3: 3
};
var objB = {
  key1: 4,
  key2: 5,
  key3: 6,
  key4: 7,
  key5: 8
}

for (var keys in objB) {
  if (!objA.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
    delete objB[keys]
  }
}
console.log(objB)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys`, `Array.filter` and `Array.reduce` to achieve this:

```js
var objA = {key1:1, key2:2, key3:3};
var objB = {key1:4, key2:5, key3:6, key4:7, key5:8}
console.log(Object.keys(objB)
    .filter(key => objA[key])
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = objB[key];
        return obj;
    }, {}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind creating a new object to replace the old one, you can use `.reduce()` on the result of `Object.entries()` like this:

```js
var objA = {key1:1, key2:2, key3:3};
var objB = {key1:4, key2:5, key3:6, key4:7, key5:8};

objB = Object.entries(objB).reduce((res, [k,v]) =>
  k in objA ? Object.assign(res, {[k]:v}) : res
, {});

console.log(objB);
```

Or to use it using a `for-of` loop, you can do this:

```js
var objA = {key1:1, key2:2, key3:3};
var objB = {key1:4, key2:5, key3:6, key4:7, key5:8};

var res = {};
for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(objB)) {
  if (k in objA) res[k] = v;
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var objA = { key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3 };
var objB = { key1: 4, key2: 5, key3: 6, key4: 7, key5: 8 };

objB = Object.keys(objB).reduce(function(result, key) {
  if (objA.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    result[key] = objB[key]
  }

  return result;
}, {});
```

This is a ES5 version which doesn't use the `delete` operator but instead constructs a new object which only has the keys from `objA` and assigns it to `objB`.

Answer (score 0):

Try a bit more modern JavaScript:

```js
function reduceObject(baseObject = {}, dataObject = {}) {
  return Object.keys(baseObject)
    .reduce((result, key) => {
      result[key] = dataObject[key];
      return result;
    }, {});
}
const objA = {key1:1, key2:2, key3:3};
const objB = {key1:4, key2:5, key3:6, key4:7, key5:8};

console.log(reduceObject(objA, objB));
console.log(reduceObject(objA));
console.log(reduceObject(undefined, objB));
console.log(reduceObject({ a: 'key' }, { a: 'thing', on: 'theFly' }));
```

Comment: this will also return keys which are in objA but not in objB

Comment: The question said: `object to have same keys of other.`

Comment: Yeah but question doesn't say that it wants keys also which are in objA and aren't in objB. (it says even it wants shared ones).

Comment: @Zlatko: That's not an accurate quote from the question. It reads that the object should *"keep"* only the keys that are in `objA`. In other words, the result should be the keys of `objB` that also exist in `objA`, or basically an intersection of those objects. The full quotation says to *"remove"* keys to obtain the result.

Comment: Yep, you're right. The quote is inacurrate, but the full sentence is also not entirely accurate. So it probably needs clarification on that side. See: `I need a way to automatically remove keys of a object to have same keys of other.` - this is incomplete. It works in his example. But if his objB had less keys or no keys, then you cannot possibly _remove_ keys to have the _same_ keys as objA. One possible way to achieve that is to interpret the question the way I did, make B have the same keys as A. That's how I have interpreted and understood the question.

Comment: I agree that the wording is a little clunky.

Comment: Yep, me too. I'll leave the answer in case it helps the author, but you're free to downvote to indicate your intent, too. That's how it should work.